# Select columns when reading in files with st_read

Tags: r, select, r-sf

I am trying to read 39 json files into a common sf dataset in R.

Here is the method I've been trying:

```
path <- "~/directory" 
file.names <- as.list(dir(path, pattern='.json', full.names=T)) 
geodata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file.names, st_read))
```

The problem is in the last line: `rbind` cannot work because the files have different numbers of columns. However, they all have three columns in common, and which I care about: `MOVEMENT_ID`, `DISPLAY_NAME` and `geometry`. How could I select only these three columns when running st_read?

I've tried running `geodata<-do.call(rbind, lapply(file.names, st_read,select=c('MOVEMENT_ID', 'DISPLAY_NAME', 'geometry')))` but, in this case, `st_read` does not seem to recognise the geometry column (error: 'no simple features geometry column pressent'). 
I've also tried to use `fread` in place of `st_read` but this doesn't work as `fread` is not adapted to spatial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `lapply` over a function that calls `st_read` and then does what you need to it, something like:

```
read_my_json = function(f){
 s = st_read(f)
 return(s[,c("MOVEMENT_ID","DISPLAY_NAME")]
}
```

(I'm pretty sure you don't have to select the geometry as well, you get that for free when selecting columns of an `sf` spatial object)

then `do.call(rbind, lapply(file.names, read_my_json))` should work.

no extra packages need to be included and it has the big advantage in that you can test this function to see how it works on a single item before throwing a thousand at it.

Comment: That is indeed fast and practical, thank you. In the last command, I think you mean `rbind`, not `cbind`, correct?

Comment: Oopsie. Yes, rbind for rows, cbind for columns, thanks. Have edited.